# How can I go through multiple sheet tabs and suffix every cell in B column?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with 20+ sheet tabs with 20+ adresses in B column with differing amounts of rows.

I would like to put a ", " suffix to every line in every tab, that would do as a quick fix.

But more preferably merge every sheet tab in one sheet with a line separation between the data sets and a header taken from the sheet tab name to tell every dataset apart.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdXDg.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const xcl = ["Sheet1","Sheet2"];//Sheets to exclude
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !~xcl.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    let arr = sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat().forEach((e,i) => {
      sh.getRange(i + 1,2).setValue(e + ', ')
    });
  })
}
```